# There is a way of get a OraclePreparedStatement insisde of a JBoss 6/7?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss

How to access OraclePreparedStatement on a JBoss ?

I end getting a org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6 from JBoss. I call "getUnderlyingStatement" method from it, and returns an "OraclePreparedStatementWrapper" (a Oracle driver internal class).

I found this [post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/27294?tstart=0) with a "solution" but not works in our case. Accessing to the internal field "preparedStatement" of these class returns a "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement" class.

Our actual code :

```
} else if (st.getClass().getName().equals   ("org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6")) {
        try {
            Class jbossWrappedSt = Class.forName("org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6");
            Method metodoUnwrap = jbossWrappedSt.getMethod ("getUnderlyingStatement");
            Object val = metodoUnwrap.invoke (st);
            Field preparedStatementField = val.getClass ().getDeclaredField ("preparedStatement");
            preparedStatementField.setAccessible (true);
            return ((PreparedStatement)preparedStatementField.get(val)); // Returns a "if (st.getClass().getName().equals   ("org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6")) {
        try {
            Class jbossWrappedSt = Class.forName("org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6");
            Method metodoUnwrap = jbossWrappedSt.getMethod ("getUnderlyingStatement");
            Object val = metodoUnwrap.invoke (st);
            Field preparedStatementField = val.getClass ().getDeclaredField ("preparedStatement");
            preparedStatementField.setAccessible (true);
            return getOraclePreparedStatement ((PreparedStatement)preparedStatementField.get(val));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ConfigException ("En getOraclePreparedStatement, error al intentar acceder a la conexión Oracle del pool de conexiones JBoss", e);
        }
} else { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to `java.sql.Connection` via

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider cp = sfi.getConnectionProvider();
Connection con = cp.getConnection();
```

From there you can get `PreparedStatement` with `Connection#prepareStatement()`

And now, some people claim that you can cast the returned `PreparedStatement` to `OraclePreparedStatement`.

Anyway, why do you need `OraclePreparedStatement`, maybe you can achieve your goal otherwise?

Comment: We need to call to "OraclePreparedStatement.setFormOfUse(int, short)"

Comment: But I end implementing a function that calls these method using reflection instead of trying to get a `OraclePreparedStatement`. With this, I could work over the T4CPreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that there isn't a way to do that, instead we end doing a method that calls setFormOfUse using Java reflexion over OraclePreparedStatementWrapper